# MySQL min() behaviour in Innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, mvcc

How does MySQL behave when you're performing a `SELECT MIN(x) FROM blah;` when at the same time, the table is undergoing thousands of `DELETE` operations?

Would the result of the min() ever show an entry which was deleted?   If not, how does it prevent returning a value from a deleted entry?

This is coming up because we have a large database where the min() is running for hours, but deletes are occurring continuously during that time.

Comment: If you want deterministic behavior, you should probably be using transactions.

Comment: I'm not asking how to ensure deterministic behaviour.   I think MySQL would handle this either by possibly returning a value for a deleted entry, or by somehow putting the select min() in a transaction by default... meaning that hours of table updates are buffered in a transaction log somewhere.

Comment: This is probably better suited to [dba.se]

Comment: @burgi, the DBA Stack Exchange describes itself as being for professional DBAs.

Comment: @mgjk what you are asking for is very niche, they will be in a better position to answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html about consistent reads in InnoDB. Each SELECT statement is guaranteed to view a kind of "snapshot" of data, that will not change while the SELECT statement is running.

So you're right, you do have a risk of the SELECT statement returning a value for `MIN(x)` that won't be there after your SELECT statement is done, because it was deleted in the meantime.

This is the price we pay for the freedom to do read queries without blocking concurrent updates/deletes.

By the way, if you want `MIN(x)` to return quickly, create an index with `x` as its first column.